# Why do I get an error when trying to import an Excel file into Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When I try to import an Excel file or enter data manually into Power BI Desktop I get the following error:

```
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The provider 'Microsoft.PowerBI.OleDb' is not registered. The following system error occurred: Class not registered’.
```

[image]

I am using Power BI Desktop x64 and Excel x32 bit.

Comment: did you try to uninstall and reinstall the latest version of Power Bi Desktop ?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. Just a note my current version of Power BI is Version: 2.106.883.0 64-bit (June 2022)

Comment: in most cases, it helps to solve this problem. Also you may try to install the 32bit version of Power Bi ...

Comment: Same here! And yesterday I installed the latest version (x64).

Comment: @UmutK please post this as an answer so that I could mark it as a solution. IT uninstalled Power BI for me and reinstalled the same version (June) and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to uninstall and reinstall the latest version of Power Bi Desktop ? in most cases, it helps to solve this problem.

Also you may try to install the 32bit version of Power Bi ...

I am glad it helped !